# What should be the return type of my Power BI function if I want to use it as axis value for my report

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to write a function which accepts a date parameter and creates hourly date and time data for that day (i.e for 24 hours). I want to use these 24 hours as axis value for my Power BI report. In what format should these values be returned so that my report gets accurate hourly graph for the date passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that you'd end up with many different Time tables -- one for each time you call the function.

You should really strive to have each table do one single thing and do it well. This means having a single Date table and a single Time table. The Date table should cover all dates across your dataset, and the time table should be date agnostic. This way you keep the responsibilities of each table distinct and you can keep using your date table as usual.

```
let
    Source = {0..23},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(
        Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(),
        {"Index"}, null, ExtraValues.Error
    ),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Converted to Table",
        {{"Index", Int64.Type}}
    ),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Changed Type", "Hour",
        each #time([Index], 0, 0),
        Time.Type
    )
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Set it up with a relation to your transaction table on a pure time column. Then use either the Index or the Time column on your axis. Note that this table only has one row per hour, so if you need a different granularity, you'll have to add a row for each minute/second/quarter hour. But this all depends on your data.